# Prevent same component tags in v-if, v-else, v-else-if from sharing a Vue instance

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a VueJS component `<managed-list>`, which I'm using twice in the same template to show two different sets of data. Each is displayed in its own `<section>` container which is toggled using `v-if` on a nav-tab.

It seems that these components are being instantiated as the same instance. I call `console.log()` in the `created` hook of the component, and on page-load I get a message to the console. However, when I tab over to show the other data table, the template for the appropriate `v-if` renders, but the `created` hook doesn't fire again.

My understanding is that when using `v-if` statements in templates, the components are properly created and destroyed. But this doesn't seem to be happening in my case. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <router-link class="nav-link" :class="{active: $route.params.tab=='reports'}" to="reports">Reports</router-link>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <router-link class="nav-link" :class="{active: $route.params.tab=='snippets'}" to="snippets">Snippets</router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <section v-if="$route.params.tab == 'reports'">
      <h2>Reports</h2>

      <managed-list 
        :imports-disabled="true" 
        prop-delete-endpoint="ReportTemplate/delete" 
        prop-resource-url="ReportTemplate"
        :prop-fetch-url="'ReportTemplate/filter?filters='+reportFilter"
        prop-edit-action="/reports/templates/edit/{?}">
      </managed-list>
    </section>

    <section v-else-if="$route.params.tab == 'snippets'">
      <h2>Snippets</h2>

      <managed-list 
        :imports-disabled="true" 
        prop-delete-endpoint="ReportTemplate/delete" 
        prop-resource-url="ReportTemplate"
        :prop-fetch-url="'ReportTemplate/filter?filters='+snippetFilter"
        prop-edit-action="/reports/templates/edit/{?}">
      </managed-list>
    </section>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import ManagedList from "./ManagedList"
import bus from '../bus.js'

export default {
  name: 'ReportTemplates',
  components: {
    ManagedList
  },
  data() {
    return {
      snippetFilter : JSON.stringify([
        ["is_snippet","=", 1]
      ]),
      reportFilter : JSON.stringify([
        ["is_snippet","=", 0]
      ])
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.snippetFilter, this.reportFilter)
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because, by default, Vue tries to save time by reusing components when it can. Your `<managed-list>` component is in both possible `<section>` tags of the `v-if` and `v-else-if` pair, so Vue is just keeping that component around instead of destroying and immediately re-rendering it.

If you want to force Vue to associate each of two `<managed-list>` tags with its own component, you should add a unique `key` attribute to each component tag:

```
<section v-if="$route.params.tab == 'reports'">
  <h2>Reports</h2>
  <managed-list key="reports" ... />
</section>

<section v-else-if="$route.params.tab == 'snippets'">
  <h2>Snippets</h2>
  <managed-list key="snippets" ... />
</section>
```

[Here's the Vue documentation on that.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key)

---

Here's a simple, illustrative example:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<p>I am child</p>',
  created() {
    console.log('created')
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { foo: 'a' }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.foo = (this.foo === 'a') ? 'b' : 'a';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggle">
    Toggle Children
  </button>

  <template v-if="foo === 'a'">
    <div> 
      A <child key="a"></child>    
    </div>
  </template>
  <template v-else-if="foo === 'b'">
    <div> 
      B <child key="b"></child>    
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed... Thanks for the detailed explanation!